# bash script to capture input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, windows-shell

I am trying to do homework assignment in which I need to check the case if when I run my bash script it failed to capture an input as supposed, and if so I have to print "Error" (the script must capture 2 arguments).
     How do I check in a script itself if it fails to capture an input when I run it?

Comment: What means 'must capture two arguments'? Is this per command line like 'bash myscript.sh arg1 arg2' or per stdin like 'echo "arg1 arg2" | bash myscript'?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is homework only two hints:

1. Read the manual for `test`
2. Read the shell manual and look for `$#`